# Python subprocess execution slower than main process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a Python method as shown below:

```
import gym

def run():
    env = gym.make('Pendulum-v1')
    env.reset()
    action = [1.0]
    for _ in range(1000):
        env.step(action)
```

I use `viztracer` to profile this method in the main process and subprocess (by `multiprocessing.Process`), respectively. It shows that the main process executes faster than the subprocess, even for the single `step` method.

Here are the profilings

**`step` method execution time in subprocess:**
[image: step method execution time in subprocess]

**`step` method execution time in the main process:**
[image: step method execution time in main process]

**`numpy.ndarray.clip` method execution time in subprocess:**
[image: numpy.ndarray.clip method execution time in subprocess]

**`numpy.ndarray.clip` method execution time in the main process:**
[image: numpy.ndarray.clip method execution time in main process]

My environment is:

- Python version: 3.8.11 (gym version:0.26.2)
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- CPU: 2 * XEON GOLD 6230

Any idea on:

- What is the cause of the issue?
- How to fix it?

Thanks.

I have tried to profile this method on different hardware, including intel i7 9750h and i9 12900h. It shows the same issue.

multiprocessing benchmark code is shown below

```
import gym
from multiprocessing import Process

def run():
    env = gym.make('Pendulum-v1')
    env.reset()
    action = [1,0]
    for _ in range(1000):
        env.step(action)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=run)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    p.close()
```

Comment: what does the multiprocessing version looks like ?

Comment: @AhmedAEK the multiprocessing is a built-in module of Python 3.8.11

Comment: i mean what does the multiprocessing benchmark code looks like.

Comment: I paste the code at the end of this question.

Comment: yep, 100% thermal throttling, you can verify that by turning off your cpu turbo boost.

Comment: One version has `action = [1,0]`, with a comma. The other version has `action = [1.0]`, with a dot. One of those is a list of two ints `1` and `0`, while the other is a list of a single float `1.0`. I don't know enough about gym to know what the consequences of that are, but it definitely looks like you're timing entirely different things there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`What is the cause of issue?`

your CPU is triggering thermal throttling in the multiprocessing version, there's also memory and cache contention that will happen.

`How to fix it?`

you can't, even if you submerged the computer in liquid nitrogen.

vendors are overspecing and pushing the numbers in single core performance, but the core's true performance under load is shown in multiprocessing work, most CPUs nowdays can work just fine at 5+ GHz in single core performance, but will fall down to 3 GHz under load.

if you turn off turbo boost you will get the same time in both, but this is just by slowing down the single core performance to be on par with the multicore performance.

Comment: The main process is doing absolutely nothing while the worker runs. It just starts the worker and immediately `join`s it, sleeping until the worker finishes. There's no way this has anything to do with single-core vs multi-core performance or one version hitting thermal throttling that the other version doesn't.

Comment: @user2357112 did you try turning turbo boost off ? i don't care if you don't like the anwer, this is the answer, and you'll reach it after days of searching.

Comment: Great answer! I verified your answer by turning off the turbo boost.